# PHP Why is this simple array showing incorrect value

Tags: php, arrays, echo

This is as simple as it gets, but I can't see why I'm getting 0 when I `echo $num[3]` from this PHP array.

`$num=[00000004,00000002,00000005,00000009]; echo $num[3];`

Comment: Preceding the number with a 0 (zero) denotes an octal notation..

Comment: This will throw a fatal error if you use PHP 7 or higher.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried other numbers and I'm seeing an octal result.  I never knew about that.  I'll need to make them a string if I want the leading zeros in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Integers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#:%7E:text=To%20use%20octal%20notation%2C%20precede,As%20of%20PHP%207.4.) Manual

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use
> hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
> notation precede the number with 0b.

Your values are actually representing octal notation and that's why you are leading to issue.

Convert them to string:

```
$num=[
    '00000004',
    '00000002',
    '00000005',
    '00000009'
  ]; 
echo $num[3];
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/ktsJY

Note:- From Php7 onward it will give you `Parse error: Invalid numeric literal`

https://3v4l.org/W3aD0

Comment: @GertB AlivetoDie's answer mentioning "octal" was the real problem.  So this is the best answer.  It is acceptable to not use the quotes in php5, but the results were showing octal numbers.

Comment: True, it is the most complete answer. Adding the php7 note was a very good idea btw. I just think that its a lot of information for a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the leading zero's, it needs to be a string, not a number:

```
$num=['00000004','00000002','00000005','00000009']; echo $num[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is not stored correct, they are stored as a number but they are strings so they need to be stored as a string. When I run your code it throws an error

```
Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal in [...][...] on line 2
```

The code below wil return 00000009

```
$num=['00000004','00000002','00000005','00000009']; echo $num[3];
```

Comment: hmmz, looks like my answer... Only php 7+ will throw an error btw

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is not correct,try this

```
$num = array("00000004","00000002","00000005","00000009");
echo $num['3'];
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the syntax??? Your answer does exactly the same as my answer..

Comment: Thanks for explaining,the values are stored as string therefore you must enclose in quotation marks.

Comment: And why would you change the [...] to array(... ), thats not needed.